# Update Active Admin Record from Slack or Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, slack

I'm mildly technical and have never worked with rails, so forgive my ignorance. Our team has a manual process where we update a company record in Active Admin with info from another team. I was wondering if there's a way I can pass information in to Active Admin from Slack, Formstack, or something similar, then update the record. From a cursory google there doesn't seem to be an API to work with. Does anyone have any guidance here?

Comment: Sorry, but this question is way to broad for Stack Overflow. For general discussion and guidance I would suggest to place your question on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Slack/). Voting to close.

Comment: ActiveAdmin is just a UI layer sitting on top of a database.  You can expose the database via an API that can be called from an other system.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very broad, but just want to highlight you what is possibility, you can consume API of Slack to do your requirement but it is not being done use ActiveAdmin individual field. Following you can perform
Setup a chat bot of Slack to use, and when someone submit data on that specific bot communication, it will hit another API on your rails project, which will update record accordingly. That mean any spoken to that user/bot of slack will come to rails api(which you have to develop) and will update database.

But if you are thinking just one single field of active admin is collected from team and rest your fill, than have to do very big changes, on record basis, so empty record is created from slack and you just go and reedit records already filled by chatbot of slack and amend it.